# Update Firebase Auth user claims via rest API

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

At the moment I update user claims in a firebase function like so:

```dart
await admin.auth().setCustomUserClaims(...);
```

However I'm moving to use CloudRun, and I need a way to update user claims via the REST API. [The docs](https://cloud.google.com/identity-platform/docs/use-rest-api) don't seem to mention a way to do this. I'm using the dart package https://pub.dev/packages/googleapis and this doesn't even include Firebase auth stuff. Does anyone know if it's possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is one of those cases where it's really handy that the Firebase Admin SDKs are open source, as we can check how it implements the [`setCustomUserClaims` function](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-admin-node/blob/e7ab2f046843c23bb95b382c3896ca104c6d75f6/src/auth/auth-api-request.ts#L1271-L1296). You can see in there that it calls the `accounts:update` auth REST endpoint, which is documented in the reference documentation for [updating a user profile](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rest/auth#section-update-profile).

So you will need to:

1. Authenticate as a user who is at least an editor on the project.
2. Build a request with a `customAttributes` property for the new claims.
3. Call the `accounts:update` auth REST endpoint.

Comment: This gives insufficent permissions error. I am assuming they are keeping some actions to be done only with service accounts. Is there a resource that shows how I can do this with REST using service accounts or any other way?

Answer (score -1):

I actually went for a solution similar to the one detailed in [this article](https://medium.com/firebase-developers/patterns-for-security-with-firebase-supercharged-custom-claims-with-firestore-and-cloud-functions-bb8f46b24e11), you mirror the user claims in firestore collection and have a trigger to update the authentication objects. This makes it simple for my rest based stuff to update claims.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).