# Firebase Authentication Disable account

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-authentication

I'm using firebase with Angular Framework,
and the business logic is that the user can't register and the admin should do that, so I used firebase rest API.
***The question here is it possible to disable any user account using firebase rest API (I Found only a Delete account)***?!

Answer (score 1):

There is no separate call for disabling account, since it's "just" an update of the user profile (as shown in the documentation on [updating a user account](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/manage-users#update_a_user) with the Admin SDK).

As far as I can tell from reading the [source code](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-admin-node/blob/4bef8fabeb39be2c527862689fe8e49e5410540f/src/auth/auth-api-request.ts#L746-L769) for the relevant Admin SDK, you should be able to pass this same `disabled` value to the `/accounts:update` [REST API](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rest/auth#section-update-profile) despite it not being mentioned in the docs.

Comment: @RenaudTarnec 
The Admin SDK calls these same end points. Since the Admin SDK can disable a user account by calling the REST API, so can your own code. It *does* indeed require that you use a different way to authenticate, as shown [here](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-admin-node/blob/4bef8fabeb39be2c527862689fe8e49e5410540f/src/auth/auth-api-request.ts#L229-L239). That code has definitely gotten more complex since I last used it, but since the Admin SDK offers this functionality on top of the REST API, you can technically do the same.

Comment: @FrankVanPufelen, thanks for the answer. I had actually deleted my comment because I remembered your [last similar answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69449375/update-firebase-auth-user-claims-via-rest-api/69451750#69451750) and I saw there that you mentioned the need for "authenticating as a user who is at least an editor on the project". I'm currently doing some tests with users of a test Firebase project to understand how we can authenticate with such an "editor" account if it not declared in the auth service. Maybe you can share some guidance, it would be great!

Comment: Thanks For your answer, I already tried update API and Path "disabled: true" value but it didn't work for me.

Comment: @AmrHassan It'll be more likely someone can help if you [show what you've tried](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Thanks For Your Advice, 
I tried to make a post request with the postman on (https://identitytoolkit.googleapis.com/v1/accounts:update?key=) With body {
 idToken: {user token}, 
 disabled: true,
}

Comment: Please edit your question to show a [minimal, complete example that any of us can run to reproduce the problem](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (read the link please, as following that guidance maximizes the chance that someone can help).